# Can I get email notification for achievements?

Tags: feature-request, support, email-notification

I want to get email notification for achievements like : **privileges, badges** earned.

I don't want to subscribe for new inbox Q/A received.

How to subscribe for that (for askubuntu)?

Further clarification: I don't expect to get notification for reputation updates because I know that it changes randomly and fast. So, I expect only privileges, and badges updates because it is earned occasionally.

Comment: Why? Can't you just go to the website?

Comment: The website does a fine job of doing this itself. It's hard to miss the green bubble. ;)

Answer (score 4):

We're looking at better ways to let people know when they have achievements, including the option to get some pushed via email.  But getting more of this to users who want it without annoying those who are highly focused on replies is a little tricky to balance:

- We don't, however, want to harass power users every time they get an up vote.
- We also don't want to become one of those sites with a million "subscription preferences", because over time those systems mostly get abused by companies who make it hard to unsubscribe:

> "You only unsubscribed from the *half-hourly* updates; how were we to know you didn't want the "every minute" ones??"

At some point, we'll likely add "new privilege updates" to existing emails, but they would likely be part of the big-picture opt-in/opt-out emails.

We might consider some ability to add summary roll-ups that include rep or badges, but I doubt it would be a vote-by-vote approach, even as an option.

Comment: I get email about inbox items if they've been there for a day without me acting on them.  (I don't remember how I set that up...)  If you decide to do email about achievements maybe you could do the same thing -- only tell people about changes they haven't already picked up on the site.

Comment: Good thing you answered, I'm pretty sure this exact request was brought up before but always downvoted and without positive scored answer, hence auto deleted after a month. (which is why I think auto deletion shouldn't occur on MSE, but that's a different matter :))