# Adding notifications for reputation changes and badges

Tags: feature-request, notifications, ios-app

I think we should be able to receive notifications in the Stack Exchange iOS app when we get/lose reputation or earn badges. We could be able to specify in the app if we want to be notified in Notification Center when one of our questions/answers was upvoted/downvoted and other changes or just be notified when somebody comments on our answers/questions or answers our questions. Is anyone capable of putting this into the app?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is needed? Right now I think notifications are either on or off... I'm not sure how easy it is to have settings for individual types of notifications.

Comment: Um, I don't think you quite understand. This is just a feature suggestion that I think would make the Stack Exchange app better, I would like these types of notifications and I'm sure others would, too. As far as making different settings for different notifications, I'm sure whoever made the iOS app would have no trouble implementing this, should they want to.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, I (personally) don't see the benefit and would better like to understand why you think this is a beneficial feature. Is it such a bad thing for someone to ask *why* you want a feature?

Comment: I see your point, but personally think it's too much work for not enough gain.

Comment: request for Android: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202512/optional-android-notifications-for-reputation-changes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is really much benefit from adding that. In my opinion, notifications are there to inform you some action should be taken. Reputation and badges don't require any action.

According to this somewhat similar [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231847/245360) about email notifications for badges and reputation, SE doesn't want to have an extensive list of options to toggle on and off, like you propose. That would mean this is a all or nothing implementation, and I don't think all users want such an option.

Comment: Agree about badges and upvotes, but if one is notified about a downvote instantly, it might help him/her take a second look, edit, etc. Good cause, but like I commented on the question itself, I don't think it is worth the rather big amount of time needed to develop such thing.

Comment: Notifications on down votes is the most requested feature SE wide. But that is declined as you know. If that is added, this could be useful indeed.