# No notifications

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

I used to get notifications for new SE messages on my phone. That is no longer the case. Notifications are fully enabled for the app in my settings.

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: This morning I got my first notification in a long time. Maybe someone fixed this today?

Comment: I did not get a notification when I got an up vote a short while ago. I can't remember whether or not I used to get them.

Comment: Am I supposed to get notifications of reputation changes on my phone? (I'm not.)

Comment: You should get a notification for this comment.  Notifications come for anything in the inbox dialog, most commonly new answers or comments.  We don't notify for items in the achievements dialog (reputation, badges, privileges).

Comment: I just got a notification for this. I guess the app works as intended now.

Comment: You may want to upvote this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263454/adding-notifications-for-reputation-changes-and-badges